# R: Missing levels of categorical variable in summary of linear model

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

In my formula I have several terms with the categorical variable `color` and `color`'s interaction with other variables. Color can be either white or red. When looking at the summary of my model, color is replaced by colorwhite with no mention of colorred. Can someone explain the mechanics behind R only showing one level of my categorical variable in the summary?

example:

`>summary(lm(foo~bar+color+color:bar))
coefficients
bar
colorwhite
colorwhite:bar`

Comment: I might be missing something, but colorred is the reference group. This is fundamental concept in categorical variables and should be covered by wikipedia (dummy variables) or http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/library/contrast_coding.htm

Comment: This question is answered (although not directly asked, I believe) in many threads which can be found by searching our site for [dummy coding](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dummy+coding+[r]+[categorical]).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: I just see Charles's reply above. I think the documents he pointed to are very helpful. Thanks  Patrick Coulombe for discussion.

If your `color` variable has only two possible values 'white' and 'red', you will have only `coefficients` for `colorwhite` and `colorwhite:bar`.

The point is that you have `intercept`. And the base case is `color` = `red`.

The`coefficient` for `colorwhite` actually reflect the effect size of `white`, being compared to that of `red`, given the `bar` as 0.

The`coefficient` for `colorwhite:bar` actually reflect the effect size of the combination of (interaction between) `white` and a unit of `bar` value, being compared to that of the combination of (interaction between) `red` and a unit of `bar` value, given the same `bar` value.

Please check this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size):

"Always present effect sizes for primary outcomes...If the units of measurement are meaningful on a practical level (e.g., number of cigarettes smoked per day), then we usually prefer an unstandardized measure (*regression coefficient* or mean difference) to a standardized measure (r or d).

— L. Wilkinson and APA Task Force on Statistical Inference (1999, p. 599)

...

The term effect size can refer to a standardized measures of effect (such as r, Cohen's d, and odds ratio), or to an unstandardized measure (e.g., the raw difference between group means and unstandardized regression coefficients). "

And also [this page](http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/analysis/interpreting_regression.htm):
"Remember that regression analysis is used to produce an equation that will predict a dependent variable using one or more independent variables. This equation has the form

Y = b1X1 + b2X2 + ... + A
where Y is the dependent variable you are trying to predict, X1, X2 and so on are the independent variables you are using to predict it, b1, b2 and so on are the coefficients or multipliers that describe *the size of the effect* the independent variables are having on your dependent variable Y, and A is the value Y is predicted to have when all the independent variables are equal to zero.

...

In simple or multiple linear regression, the *size of the coefficient* for each independent variable gives you *the size of the effect* that variable is having on your dependent variable, and the sign on the coefficient (positive or negative) gives you the direction of the effect. In regression with a single independent variable, the coefficient tells you how much the dependent variable is expected to increase (if the coefficient is positive) or decrease (if the coefficient is negative) when that independent variable increases by one. In regression with multiple independent variables, the coefficient tells you how much the dependent variable is expected to increase when that independent variable increases by one, *holding all the other independent variables constant*. Remember to keep in mind the units which your variables are measured in.
"

Comment: The coefficients are not effect sizes

Comment: Also, the coefficient for `colorwhite` is the predicted difference in the score on the DV between white and red *when bar = 0*.

Comment: Please check this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size): "The term effect size can refer to a standardized measures of effect (such as r, Cohen's d, and odds ratio), or to an unstandardized measure (e.g., the raw difference between group means and unstandardized regression coefficients). " I think you are emphasizing the effect size as standardized measures of effect, namely, the "effect size" of regression. What I said is reasonable as an unstandardized measure.

Comment: And please also check this [page](http://dss.princeton.edu/online_help/analysis/interpreting_regression.htm):
Y = b1X1 + b2X2 + ... + A
where Y is the dependent variable you are trying to predict, X1, X2 and so on are the independent variables you are using to predict it, b1, b2 and so on are the coefficients or multipliers that describe *the size of the effect* the independent variables are having on your dependent variable Y, and A is the value Y is predicted to have when all the independent variables are equal to zero.

Comment: Yes, that seems right. When I hear effect size I certainly don't think of this "unstandardized" kind. Note that my comment on the interpretation of the `colorwhite` coefficient in the presence of the `colorwhite:bar` term still stands.

Comment: I do not mean what you said is wrong, or does not stand. I mean what I said stands, and we may not say something is not true simply because it is not the thing we have seen/used.

Comment: Apologies, perhaps I should have been clearer. You should edit your answer to reflect the fact that the interpretation of the `colorwhite` coefficient applies only when bar=0 (when bar is different from 0, the predicted difference between red and white is NOT the value of the `colorwhite` coefficient)

Comment: You are right. However, not only bar=0. Actually for any same bar value in those two scenarios.

Comment: This is not right @PeterH. The predicted difference between red and white is $\hat{\beta}_{colorwhite} + \hat{\beta}_{colorwhite*bar} \cdot bar$. Therefore, the predicted difference between red and white is equal to $\hat{\beta}_{colorwhite}$ only when $bar=0$.

Comment: @PatrickCoulombe, yes, i think you are right. Please see the update above.